# Reading a value from application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a value that's defined in application.ini

```
conditions.time= 50
```

How can I read it in an zend action the zend way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my approach, which you can use anywhere in the application:

```
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Options extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Options separator delimiterm e.g.
     * option.subkey or
     * option/subkey
     */
    const DELIMITER = '.';

    /**
     * Retrieve application options from bootstrap
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $front = $this->getFrontController();
        $bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
        if (null === $bootstrap) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to find bootstrap');
        }

        return $bootstrap->getOptions();
    }

    /**
     * Get array key if exists, otherwise returns null
     * 
     * @param array $values
     * @param string $key
     * @return mixed 
     */
    private static function _getValue($values, $key) 
    {   
        if (is_array($values) && isset($values[$key])) {

            return $values[$key];  
        } 

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get application option form bootstrap
     * 
     * @example
     * $options = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('options')
     * ->get('conditions.time', 'defaultvalue');
     * 
     * @param   string $section
     * @param   mixed $default
     * @return  Zend_Config
     */
    public function get($section = null, $default = null)
    {
        $value = $this->getOptions();

        if (null !== $section && is_string($section)) {
            if (false === strpos($section, self::DELIMITER)) {
                $value = $this->_getValue($value, $section);
            } else {
                $sections = explode(self::DELIMITER, $section);        
                foreach ($sections as $section) {
                    $value = $this->_getValue($value, $section);
                    if (null === $value) {

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        if (null === $value) {

            return $default;
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * @param   string $section
     * @param   mixed $default
     * @return  Zend_Config
     */
    public function direct($section = null, $default = null)
    {
        return $this->get($section, $default);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Zend_Config_Ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html)

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('my/ini/file.ini');
echo $config->conditions->time; // 50
```

Comment: This causes that the config file is read at least twice = not recommended. Those values are already in memory (in the front controller's *bootstrap* param), so you should retrieve them from there.

Answer (score 5):

The Application's `Bootstrap.php` has access to the `application.ini` using `$this->getOptions()`, you could store the value you want in your registry something like this:

```
  public function _initConditions()
  {
    $config = $this->getOptions();

    if (isset($config['conditions']))
    {

      $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();

      $registry->conditions = $config['conditions'];

    }
  }
```

You could then access your conditions using the registry, in much the same way that you set them here.

Comment: What's the point of storing in the registry, instead reading directly from bootstrap?

Comment: Because whenever you need the value, the bootstrap may or may not be readily available when you need it?  Not all code needing configuration is defined in the Controllers...

Answer (score 4):

Here is an action helper for that :

```
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Config
    extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function direct()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getActionController()->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        $ns = strtolower(trim($bootstrap->getAppNamespace(), '_'));
        return $bootstrap->getOption($ns);
    }
}
```

You have to put your application namespace as a prefix :

```
; application.ini
My.conditions.time= 50
```

You can use it in a controller like this :

```
$config = $this->_helper->config();
$this->view->time = $config['conditions']['time'];
```

Comment: This is a nice helper, except it won't work as static one. You should get the bootstrap from front controller if available. Next thing it needs to check, that the config array keys do exists.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `getenv('conditions.time')`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function.